# MySQL using table columns in function to create alias to be used in sorting

Tags: mysql, select

It sounds more complicated than it actually is. Here is what I'm trying to do within the SELECT part:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(
          UCASE(
                 SUBSTRING(offset_unit,1,CHAR_LENGTH(offset_unit)-1)
                ),1,'2003-01-02') as offset_date
```

**offset_unit** is a VARCHAR column in the database. It contains one of the following: "Hours","Minutes".

**offset** is an INT.

I am trying to convert the offset_unit to uppercase, after I have removed the last character ('s') so I can have a proper interval (MINUTE, HOUR...) so I can get a date that I can use in sorting afterwards, but MySQL keeps throwing an error. I have tested each step by adding one function at a time, and it only fails after I add TIMESTAMPADD. If I enter MINUTE manually then it works.

Any way to get this working?

Additional info: I am running this in CakePHP 1.3, in a find, within the 'fields' array, but that shouldn't be important.

Comment: What is the MySQL error you get? Why are there backslashes in your query?

Comment: @Jocelyn just the standard "You have an error in your SQL syntax", nothing helpful. Oops, the backslashes are from the PHP code, editing them out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can be easily achived by using `CASE WHEN` clause as:

```
SELECT (CASE 
            WHEN offset_unit = 'HOURS' 
                   THEN TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,`offset`,'2003-01-02')
            WHEN offset_unit = 'MINUTES' 
                   THEN TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,`offset`,'2003-01-02')
        END) AS offset_date
FROM my_table;
```

[SEE SQLFIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c780d/1)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `TIMESTAMPADD` does not take a string as the first argument, but a *unit* keyword, for example `MINUTE`. My guess is that you need to do this in two steps, first get the unit and then construct a query with the correct keyword.